# Route calculation failed and simulating re-routing

Tags: android, skmaps, skobbler-maps

I am using Skobbler sample Android SDK (downloaded from [here](http://developer.skobbler.com/support#download)) to write navigation application , it works perfect if I run application from Android studio but when I install application using generated APK, it usually fails on route calculation and in logs all i get is:

```
06-04 10:09:43.435    6285-6285/com.skobbler.sdkdemo D/SKMaps﹕ SKMapSurfaceView----@setZoom  11.0
06-04 10:09:43.435    6285-6285/com.skobbler.sdkdemo D/SKMaps﹕ SKMapSurfaceView---- centerMapOnPosition [101.6156902,3.0311728]
06-04 10:09:43.435    6285-6285/com.skobbler.sdkdemo D/SKMaps﹕ SKRouteManager---- @clearAllRoutesFromCache
06-04 10:09:43.436    6285-6285/com.skobbler.sdkdemo D/SKMaps﹕ SKRouteManager---- @calculateRoute SKRouteSettings [startCoordinate=[101.6156902,3.0311728], destinationCoordinate=[101.6156,3.03496], routeMode=CAR_FASTEST, alternativeRouteModes=null, routeConnectionMode=HYBRID, downloadRouteCorridor=true, routeCorridorWidthInMeters=2000, waitForCorridorDownload=false, destinationIsPoint=true, tollRoadsAvoided=false, highWaysAvoided=false, avoidFerries=false, noOfRoutes=1, countryCodesReturned=false, extendedPointsReturned=false, viaPoints=null, useRoadSlopes=false, exposeRoute=true, filterAlternatives=false, requestAdvices=true, bicycleWalk= false, bicycleCarryAvoided= false]
06-04 10:09:43.437    6285-6285/com.skobbler.sdkdemo D/SKMaps﹕ SKRouteManager----@clearCurrentRoute
06-04 10:09:43.437    6285-6285/com.skobbler.sdkdemo D/SkobblerNG﹕ clear route
06-04 10:09:43.437    6285-6285/com.skobbler.sdkdemo D/SkobblerNG﹕ clear route final
06-04 10:09:43.439    6285-6285/com.skobbler.sdkdemo D/SKMaps﹕ SKUtils----Return calculated device type HIGH
06-04 10:09:43.440    6285-6285/com.skobbler.sdkdemo D/SKMaps﹕ SKRouteManager---- Calculate route setroute SKRouteSettings [startCoordinate=[101.6156902,3.0311728], destinationCoordinate=[101.6156,3.03496], routeMode=CAR_FASTEST, alternativeRouteModes=null, routeConnectionMode=HYBRID, downloadRouteCorridor=true, routeCorridorWidthInMeters=2000, waitForCorridorDownload=false, destinationIsPoint=true, tollRoadsAvoided=false, highWaysAvoided=false, avoidFerries=false, noOfRoutes=1, countryCodesReturned=false, extendedPointsReturned=false, viaPoints=null, useRoadSlopes=false, exposeRoute=true, filterAlternatives=false, requestAdvices=true, bicycleWalk= false, bicycleCarryAvoided= false]
06-04 10:09:43.440    6285-6285/com.skobbler.sdkdemo D/SkobblerNG﹕ Java_com_skobbler_ngx_routing_SKRouteManager_setroute
06-04 10:09:43.440    6285-6285/com.skobbler.sdkdemo D/SkobblerNG﹕ No Via points added to the route
06-04 10:09:43.442    6285-6285/com.skobbler.sdkdemo D/SkobblerNG﹕ Java_com_skobbler_ngx_routing_SKRouteManager_setroute final
06-04 10:09:43.445    6285-6344/com.skobbler.sdkdemo D/SKMaps﹕ SKRouteManager---- @onRouteCalculationFailed called  with SKRoutingErrorCode =ROUTE_CANNOT_BE_CALCULATED
06-04 10:09:43.447    6285-6344/com.skobbler.sdkdemo W/SKMaps﹕ SKRouteManager---- @onAllRoutesCompleted called
```

Also, is there any way to simluate the re-routing when using navigation in `SKNavigationType.SIMULATION` mode?
I tried changing current user location explicitly inside `onCurrentPositionUpdate(SKPosition currentPosition)` method like this, but it isn't working:

```
@Override
public void onCurrentPositionUpdate(SKPosition currentPosition) {
    iteration++;

    this.currentPosition = currentPosition;
    if (mapView != null) {

        if(iteration >= 5) {
            Toast.makeText(MapActivity.this, "Changed location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            this.currentPosition = new SKPosition();
            this.currentPosition.setCoordinate(new SKCoordinate(101.618133, 3.025863));
        }

        mapView.reportNewGPSPosition(this.currentPosition);
    }
}
```

Comment: For simulating the re-routing, you have to use the blockRoad method from SKNavigationManager. Please check the doc here: http://developer.skobbler.ro/docs/android/com/skobbler/ngx/navigation/SKNavigationManager.html#blockRoad%28double%29

Comment: @SylviA your comment should be answer as it is working using blockRoad method

Comment: @Waqas did you ever figure out the cause of your ROUTE_CANNOT_BE_CALCULATED error? I've been seeing issues where any routes I attempt to calculate are failing if they include points that are not currently cached by the mapview. Usually in that case, the connectionMode of HYBRID or ONLINE should dictate that the SDK make a call to the Skobbler API to determine the route information, but I don't see that happening in my case and wondered if that was what you experienced. Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simulating the re-routing, you have to use the blockRoad method from SKNavigationManager. Please check the doc here: http://developer.skobbler.ro/docs/android/com/skobbler/ngx/navigation/SKNavigationManager.html#blockRoad%28double%29